# Can local AST transformations use non-sdk classes?

Tags: groovy

I have an local Groovy AST transformation that I'm applying at the class level. This transformation adds a method to the targeted class.

As soon as I attempt to use classes in the transformation's code from a jar I'm importing as part of the build, I run into an exception "unable to resolve class". In the example below, it's org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Abs.

When I examine the sourceUnit classLoader's urls ([URLClassLoader.getURLs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#getURLs%28%29)), I only find the path to my compiled source and don't see the list of jars that compilation pulls in (among them the commons math jar).

Can a local AST transformation make use of classes from a jar pulled in during compile time? If so, how do I get the transformation to resolve the class (I tried explicitly adding to the sourceUnit classLoader's urls without success)? If not, will a global AST transformation work instead?

```
void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
    try {
        ClassNode annotatedClass = (ClassNode) astNodes[1]
        MethodNode newMethod = makeMethod(annotatedClass)
        annotatedClass.addMethod(newMethod)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println 'Failed to apply transform'
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

MethodNode makeMethod(ClassNode source) {
    def ast = new AstBuilder().buildFromString(CompilePhase.INSTRUCTION_SELECTION, false, '''
        def added() {
            println new org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Abs().value(-3.0)
            println 'Added'
        }
'''
    )
    return (MethodNode) ast[1].methods.find { it.name == 'added' }
}
```

The complete example is available with build files [in a Github repository here](https://github.com/mcholick/gradle_ast_example/tree/add_import)

Comment: At first sight, this looks like an `AstBuilder` limitation or bug to me. AST transform code should avoid loading class objects used in the transformed or generated code on its own (as in `ClassLoader#loadClass`) , and must not attach such class objects to the AST, as this may cause class loader conflicts with the compiler (depending on the environment). But neither is the case here.

Comment: When I "./gradlew run" the linked project it seems to work fine.

Comment: I see now that the linked project does not contain the problematic code.

Comment: The link is to a specific branch Jeff. Switch to add_import